# Accessing Database(doctrine) from a twig template in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have a twig template and I want to make a query from the template. In another word, I want access database from a twig template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. you should always pass the variables you want to use in the controller.

Answer (score 4):

You can't and shouldn't do this. The view should not be doing complex logic.  Handle the data retreival in the controller and pass the data to the twig template as a variable.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, I just have a special case where it will much easier if I can do that. instead hard coding extra functions. Other frameworks support that such as Ruby On Rails.

Comment: If you must, you can create a [custom twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).  Again, I would advise against it.  Just because another framework supports something does not make it a good idea.  You may also want to look at [embedding controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers).